# why is error 404 when trying to post on my local page

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to got object on other local page and I can not just export variable.
I need to realize post request when press the button.
I was trying to do post request, but got error: "POST http://localhost:9000/bag.html 404 (Not Found)", url is correct so I don't know what to do.

```
let response = fetch('/bag.html', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(order_pizza)
});
console.log(response)
```

Comment: How are you running this code? You could only POST to `/bag.html` if a webserver accepts a request on that path. Also note that POSTing to a HTML page won't do anything in and of itself, you would need some kind of server-side logic to reply to this request.

Comment: Tell me please what I need to do for solve the problem, I'm new in web-developing, so sorry if my questions a little stupid.

Comment: You're gonna have to tell a little bit more about your setup. What does `bag.html` look like? Where is the sample code you posted above running (on a webserver like Apache or Nginx, or served from a NodeJS app, for example)? Is it running in a browser or in a node environment?